# how to draw a grid on a UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, grid

i want to create a grid with 20x20 squares with horizontal and vertical lines.
My goal is to add a gesture recognizer to get the location of the square.

How can i create a grid on the UIView?

Thanks

Comment: Use UICollectionView. See tutorial here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=uicollectionview+tutorial&oq=uicollectio&aqs=chrome.1.57j59j0l2j60j62.4307j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=yvYM_PN1D4X7c8bRiAE_JQ&pq=uicollectionview%20tutorial&cp=1&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=uicollectionview+tutorial&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Uollectionview+tutorial&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk&fp=ec94f01a283cf05e&biw=1024&bih=592

Comment: subclass UIView, and override the drawRect: selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options
1. If your deployment target is ios6.0 then you can use UICollectionView, It provides all the necessary delegates to achieve what you want
2. second option is to construct a custom cell with square(ImageView ).

Hope it will help you.. :)

Thankx